# Dynamic ObjectID ref for a subdocument inside an array in the parent document

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to create a dynamic ref for an object ID stored inside a property of a subdocument. The property can reference multiple models (even models registered in a different mongoose database instance) so I use the model instance directly instead of a model name.

```
const subSchema = new Schema({
    category: String,
    ref: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: function() {
            return this.category === 'catA' ? CategoryAModel : CategoryBModel // imports model instances
        }
    }
})

const parentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    children: [subSchema]
})

const ParentModel = db.model('Parent', parentSchema)
```

As you can see, the `ref` property is the Object ID of either a document from `CategoryAModel` or `CategoryBModel`. I started creating documents for this model, such as the following:

```
const data = {
    name: 'Test Data',
    children: [
        {
            category: 'catA',
            ref: '658e9f1901f3da2c14920401' // <- existing document from CategoryAModel
        },
        {
            category: 'catB',
            ref: '654995e0c89d1c19c84e77b7' // <- existing document from CategoryBModel
        }
    ]
}
```

But when i tried to `populate` this, the `ref` for `category: 'catA'` becomes null (despite existing). I logged the `this` context in the `ref`'s ref function and saw that `this` refers to the document being processed (same shape as the data above), and that `this.category` is undefined because it's actually inside the `children` array. Essentially making the `ref` always result in being the `CategoryBModel`

Since it's an array, how would I go and make a dynamic reference? Is there a way to access the index of the `subSchema` being referred to?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`refPath`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-refpath) instead. Mongoose has designed the `populate` method to use the `refPath` option for dynamic models and will meet your needs.

Use it like so:

```js
const subSchema = new Schema({
    category: String,
    ref: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: 'children.classifier', //< refPath should point to classifier
    },
    classifier: {
       type: String,
       enum: ['CategoryAModel', 'CategoryBModel'] //< The name of your models
    }
})
```

Now when you save your `Parent` documents the `children` objects should have which model you want to populate with stored in that `classifier` string. Your data will look like:

```js
const data = {
   name: 'Test Data',
   children: [
      {
         category: 'catA',
         ref: ObjectId("658e9f1901f3da2c14920401"), // <- existing document from CategoryAModel
         classifier: 'CategoryAModel'
      },
      {
         category: 'catB',
         ref: ObjectId("654995e0c89d1c19c84e77b7"), // <- existing document from CategoryBModel
         classifier: 'CategoryBModel'
      }
   ]
}
```

Now you can populate like so:

```js
const parents = await ParentModel.find({}).populate("children.ref");
```

Comment: I can't use a simple string for the classifier, as some of the referenced models are in a different database. If I use a string, I would get an error "Schema hasn't been registered for model 'x'". So I use the model instance instead.

Comment: Yes, I see your problem. Mongoose will use the current connection to look in the models object to find your models but if you have used createConnection to connect to different databases then they won't be in the same connection object. I would have assumed `this` referred to the child schema rather than the parent schema when you logged `this` in the `ref` function but since you checked and it doesn't then have you tried `return this.children.category === 'catA' ... ` within your original codebase? @Echo